# Regex for nginx log parser

Tags: python, regex, nginx

I made the following regular expression for parsing ngnix log

```
log_1 = "1.169.137.128 -  - [29/jun/2017:07:10:50 +0300] "GET /api/v2/banner/1717161 http/1.1" 200 2116 "-" "Slotovod" "-" "1498709450-2118016444-4709-10027411" "712e90144abee9" 0.199"
```

My test cases (https://regex101.com/r/Eyhxod/1)

```
lineformat = re.compile(r"""(?P<ipaddress>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}) -  - \[(?P<dateandtime>\d{2}\/[a-z]{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (\+|\-)\d{4})\] \"GET (?P<url>.+?(?=\ http\/1.1")) http\/1.1" \d{3} \d+ "-" (?P<http_user_agent>.+?(?=\ )) "-" "(?P<x_forwaded_for>(.+?))" "(?P<http_xb_user>(.+?))" (?P<request_time>[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)""",re.IGNORECASE)
```

Output:

```
data = re.search(lineformat, log_1)
data.groupdict()

{'ipaddress': '1.169.137.128',
 'dateandtime': '29/jun/2017:07:10:50 +0300',
 'url': '/api/v2/banner/1717161',
 'http_user_agent': '"Slotovod"',
 'x_forwaded_for': '1498709450-2118016444-4709-10027411',
 'http_xb_user': '712e90144abee9',
 'request_time': '0.199'}
```

I believe I should make it more robust towards edge cases and broken logs. Also I consider splitting my long expression into a smaller one. 
Any advices towards the best-practices are appreciated.

Comment: Isn't there a commonly known Python module for parsing these log files? You are for sure not the first person in the world to try this.

Answer (score 2):

At the very least, use verbose mode so you can see the whole thing at once.  Remember to explicitly include whitespace.

```
lineformat = re.compile(r"""
   (?P<ipaddress>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s+
   -\s+
   -\s+
   \[(?P<dateandtime>\d{2}\/[a-z]{3}\/\d{4}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (\+|\-)\d{4})\]\s+
   \"GET (?P<url>.+?(?=\ http\/1.1")) http\/1.1"\s+
   \d{3}\s+
   \d+\s+
   "-"\s+
   (?P<http_user_agent>.+?(?=\ ))\s+
   "-"\s+
   "(?P<x_forwaded_for>(.+?))"\s+
   "(?P<http_xb_user>(.+?))"\s+
   (?P<request_time>[+-]?([0-9]*[.])?[0-9]+)
   """,
   re.IGNORECASE | re.VERBOSE)
```